# Ideal formed by the collection of polynomials whose terms are of degree at least 2.

Tags: abstract-algebra

$\mathbb{Z}[X]=R$ is the ring of polynomials in x with integers coefficients.

$I$ is the collection of polynomials whose terms are of degree at least 2.

$\frac{R}{I}$ the quotient ring is given by polynomials of degree at most 1.

Two polynomials are in the same coset of I if and only if they differ by a polynomial whose terms are of degree at least 2. A complete set of rapresentatives for the quotient $\frac{R}{I}$ is given by polynomials $a\cdot x +b$ of degree at most 1.
Now I have a question about multiplication in the quotient.

$(1+3x)\cdot (-4+5x)=(-4-7x+15\cdot x^2)=-4-7\cdot x$.

$x^2=0$ in the quotient.

I thought this:

$x^2=x^2+0\cdot x+0$.

so x^2 in the quotient ring is in the 0 coset (0+I)??? Is this why x^2=0 in the quotient?

Because $x^2\in I$, then x^2=0? Is that right?

Comment: Well, $x^2 = 0 + I$ is just another way of saying that $x^2 \in I$.

Comment: @Travis Willse and so mod I x^2=0?

Comment: $a=b$ in $R/I$ iff $a-b\in I$. So $x^2=0$ in $R/I$.

Comment: @pollaris Yes, yet another way of writing the same thing is $x^2 \equiv 0 \pmod I$, though that's less common in the context of rings.